# Catch Duplicate Entry OleDbException & Over-write

Tags: c#, oledb

[image]

I get this error while processing entries when trying to add rows to my Access database. The issue is that some of the entries I'm processing are unique, and some may have a duplicate primary key with updates to the related columns. But, since some have a duplicated primary key, everything being processed fails.

I want to over-write the duplicate entries with the new data and add the new entries. How do I do this?

I did some testing below to try and get the part of the issue with everything failing solved using a try / catch block, to no avail:

```
            using (OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\Weather Cruncher\\wcMainDB.accdb"))
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into stations_NOAA " +
                    "([stationID],[stationName],[stationMinDate],[stationMaxDate],[stationDataCoverage]," +
                    "[stationLatitude],[stationLongitude],[stationElevation],[stationElevationUnit])" +
                    "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                cmd.Connection = myCon;
                myCon.Open();

                // Populate Access Database
                foreach (Station loc in noaa.results)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationID", loc.id); // Short Text data type
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationName", loc.name); // Short Text data type
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationMinDate", loc.mindate); // Short Text data type
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationMaxDate", loc.maxdate); // Short Text data type
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationDataCoverage", loc.datacoverage); // Number data type
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationLatitude", loc.latitude); // Number data type
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationLongitude", loc.longitude); // Number data type
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationElevation", loc.elevation); // Number data type
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationElevationUnit", loc.elevationUnit); // Short Text data type
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (ex.Message.Contains("duplicate values")) // It is a primary key violation, ignore
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Dupe skipped.");
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() + "\n\n" + ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

It was processing 20 queries, of which 15 where unique. I watched it step-thru while comparing the primary keys to the data the program was processing. How can these two issues be addressed?

Comment: You need to do an "update" instead of a "insert" for the records that already exist.

Comment: Is the proper approach to do this in the catch block similar to how I have it set up, or do I need to first check if a duplicate exists, then act accordingly? I will be processing up to 10K queries at a time and am concerned about efficiency

Comment: No, definitely not the "proper approach" if efficiency is a concern.

Comment: Could you offer more info? A "count" then "insert" or "update" depending on result is 20K actions vs 10K using the catch block 'hack' in this instance

Comment: Throwing exceptions is slow.  Your code should never throw an exception unless something is actually wrong.  The extra 10K lookups will be an order of magnitude faster over even 2K exceptions.  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good reads. It made plenty of sense.

Comment: How does that set of questions/answers show that performing this extra set of lookups will be faster? Assuming duplicates only happen maybe a few hundred times during this iteration, I disagree. Performing an extra lookup that will happen 10k times is certainly not faster than what the original solution would do.

Comment: @djsoteric It didn’t address that specifically, however reading up on the principle of least astonishment and the comments/links in that linked answer proved that my attempted solution was very bad practice.

Comment: It's certainly not best practice, however it's not so bad if you use then `when` keyword to filter your exceptions as that's why it was created. However, sometimes you have performance-critical actions so the comment is misleading and could misdirect someone reading it. What I would do instead is pass in all of your new primary key values into one query using IN, if supported, to return the existing values and use a localized hashset to insert or update based on the results of that query.

Comment: @djsoteric I understand what you’re saying but I would need to add new code to iterate through my dataset (API response) to get all 10K primary keys, then pass a very long comparison statement to Access before iterating through the dataset again to get the other 8 values for each primary key, once we’re pat the fork in the road where we decide whether to insert or update. Do you see things differently?

Comment: You would just need one `.Select` statement like `things.Select(x => x.id).ToHashSet()`. It's just a few more lines of code but would presumably save a lot of time. 1 db call for the same info you're getting in 10000. I'm not sure how well access handles 10k items in an IN but I've used it with a lot more on rare occasions in other dbms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps consider something like this... assuming that Station_ID is a unique field...

```
foreach (Station loc in noaa.results)
{
    cmdCount.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from stations_NOAA WHERE StationId = @station_id";
    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@station_id", loc.id);
    int count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();

    if (count > 0)
    {
         // UPDATE STATEMENT
         cmd.CommandText "UPDATE stations_NOAA Set stationMinDate = @stationMinDate, Set StationMaxDate = @stationMaxDate, ...
             where StationID = @stationID;"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationID", loc.id); // Short Text data type
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationMinDate", loc.mindate); // Short Text data type
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationMaxDate", loc.maxdate); // Short Text data type
        ...
        ...
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
    {
         // INSERT STATEMENT
         commandText = ("Insert into stations_NOAA " +
                        "([stationID],[stationName],[stationMinDate],[stationMaxDate],[stationDataCoverage]," +
                        "[stationLatitude],[stationLongitude],[stationElevation],[stationElevationUnit])" +
                        "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationID", loc.id); // Short Text data type
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationMinDate", loc.mindate); // Short Text data type
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationMaxDate", loc.maxdate); // Short Text data type
        ...
        ...
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

And if all the parameters are the same in the Update and the Insert then this pattern:

```
foreach (Station loc in noaa.results)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) from stations_NOAA WHERE StationId = @station_id", myConnection);
    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@station_id", loc.id);
    int count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();

    if (count > 0)
        cmd.CommandText "UPDATE stations_NOAA " _
            "Set stationMinDate = @stationMinDate, " _
            "Set StationMaxDate = @ StationMaxDate, " _
               ...
            "where StationID = @stationID;"

    else
        commandText = "Insert into stations_NOAA " +
                        "([stationID],[stationName],[stationMinDate],[stationMaxDate],[stationDataCoverage]," +
                        "[stationLatitude],[stationLongitude],[stationElevation],[stationElevationUnit])" +
                        "values (@stationID,@stationMinDate, @ ...)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationID", loc.id); // Short Text data type
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationMinDate", loc.mindate); // Short Text data type
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationMaxDate", loc.maxdate); // Short Text data type
    ...
    ...

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

But that only works if both the Insert and Update have the same fields and it's a lot cleaner/easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the help & explanation on avoiding my creative solution in your comments above.